# Simplify Typescript expression to recursive

Tags: arrays, typescript, recursion, indexing, typing

How could one simplify this type into a recursive type:

```
[
keyof T,
keyof T[keyof T],
keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't really support recursive types where the recursion happens at the same object depth, such as in tuples.  You'd need circular conditional types, which are currently forbidden (see [microsoft/TypeScript#26980](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980)).  You can trick the compiler into evaluating such types, but these tricks are *really* not supported (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980#issuecomment-438722312) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980#issuecomment-566152178)), so if you use these tricks and the compiler explodes, it's your job to pick up the pieces of broken compiler (that means, don't use it in production code).

The closest I can imagine getting is something like this:

---

First, I want to make some sense of the unspecified `T` in your type:

```
type Manual<T> = [
    keyof T,
    keyof T[keyof T],
    keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]]
]
```

---

Now I will define type functions `K` and `X`.  `K<T>` just maps `keyof` over the properties of `T`, and `X<T>` takes a tuple argument `T`, maps `V[keyof V]` over each of its properties, and prepends the first element to it:

```
type K<T> = { [K in keyof T]: keyof T[K] };
type X<T extends any[]> =
    ((h: T[0], ...t: { [K in keyof T]: T[K][keyof T[K]] }) => void) extends
    ((...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
```

Then, your type `Manual<T>` can be expressed like this:

```
type PartiallyAutomated<T> = K<X<X<[T]>>>;
// type PartiallyAutomated<T> = 
//  [keyof T, keyof T[keyof T], keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]]]
```

So far everything I've done is supported, so you can write `K<X<X<[T]>>>` or `K<X<X<X<[T]>>>>`, etc.  If you want to tell the compiler "do `K<X<X<...[T]...>>>` to produce a tuple of length `N`", that involves cheating with circular conditional types, or unrolling the loop in some way.

---

Here's the cheating method, which is [NOT SUPPORTED](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223#issuecomment-513187373):

```
// not supported
type Evil<N extends number, T, V extends any[] = [T]> =
    { 0: K<V>, 1: Evil<N, T, X<V>> }[N extends V['length'] ? 0 : 1]

type FullyAutomated<T> = Evil<3, T>;
// type FullyAutomated<T> =
//  [keyof T, keyof T[keyof T], keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]]]
```

or you can unroll the (illegal) loop into a (legal but redundant) set of nearly-identical types like this:

```
// supported but redundant
type Redundant<N extends number, T, V extends any[] = [T]> = N extends V['length'] ? K<V> : R0<N, T, X<V>>;
type R0<N extends number, T, V extends any[] = [T]> = N extends V['length'] ? K<V> : R1<N, T, X<V>>;
type R1<N extends number, T, V extends any[] = [T]> = N extends V['length'] ? K<V> : R2<N, T, X<V>>;
type R2<N extends number, T, V extends any[] = [T]> = N extends V['length'] ? K<V> : R3<N, T, X<V>>;
type R3<N extends number, T, V extends any[] = [T]> = N extends V['length'] ? K<V> : R4<N, T, X<V>>;
type R4<N extends number, T, V extends any[] = [T]> = N extends V['length'] ? K<V> : R5<N, T, X<V>>;
type R5<N extends number, T, V extends any[] = [T]> = N extends V['length'] ? K<V> : R6<N, T, X<V>>;
type R6<N extends number, T, V extends any[] = [T]> = N extends V['length'] ? K<V> : RX<N, T, X<V>>;
type RX<N extends number, T, V extends any[] = [T]> = N extends V['length'] ? K<V> : never; // bail out at depth 7

type AlsoAutomated<T> = Redundant<3, T>;
// type AlsoAutomated<T> = 
//  [keyof T, keyof T[keyof T], keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]]]
```

---

All of `PartiallyAutomated`, `FullyAutomated`, and `AlsoAutomated` evaluate to the same type function as `Manual`.  Is it worth it?  I kind of doubt it, since you said "simplify" and all of the solutions seem more complicated than your original definition.  Maybe if you wanted a tuple of length `6` instead of `3` like

```
[keyof T, keyof T[keyof T], keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]], 
 keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]][keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]]], 
 keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]][keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]]][
 keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]][keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]]]], 
 keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]][keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]]][
 keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]][keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]]]][
 keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]][keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]]][
 keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]][keyof T[keyof T][keyof T[keyof T]]]]]]
```

you'd start seeing the benefit of having the compiler generate the type for you, but right now I'd suggest your original tuple is simple enough.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgOwK5wDYB4AqA+KBeKAbQFgAoKCqAawhAHsAzKTAGjMutsecJvqcwBdNuUp9umXlwGCp-HuJmCyy8mVCQoAaSy4CAbyJaoASwSd5QgFwWJhLYKgBfANzrw0ABpYoEAB7AEAgAJgDOUIgghIJ67JQAFPEAFjaSAAzCUAB0OcA2hvam5orMgqn2siWSDo5OAJT4uABudCbBDf6BIaFxFIk5WQBONmYMEINQAEoNeM2t7VAA-FNQNggQTeNupO6aAApwg8AmaKggAIJIwHQAtnCBwbr42uje3oRC2F-bAPQ-UBpoAcjidUGdLtc7g8ngQyH8KHIJCxbAJETJkVU0aUsZIqoJ8WQ4f8EHRgFBQkgwGA6EcIMFdtAAKJNEwYAByvgCQTCUGQNwARuNkawoAA1TldHmRaLPD4xfC9KCGNI2HSi7DIgCMNmZrPQbOFyO86twTkIHM63PCosIAHJUEEAObAJK2xzLNKrKCa1QMqAAMSQYIuV1u9zpMKguowAGZhdhfv9AQGg+DQ1CIzgFaR4UQqhjpApC0IC5YcZVi+WCTsc-8KVSaQ8oPyrlBBnSkCFEMA-ZMO12EMB9RKrbykAKhcxkeLLd0Iggoo4CHK9FALVy5zb7U6XW6li91V7Jml9YaoMbvr2T+vJeE+YLBmeZxupQuZcvPs8b6Otw6EM7XXdA9cBsSZNVPKdz3QE1tmTMDh1nHl70nEVn1vedF1lT8CG-Tc7T-AC92WNUQKmAAmCCRQvBNewo3CkPHB8nxHOdpSXIhsLXFieV-HdAP3EijxjSijWgy9SDg4T6LvRiUOnbjwjYrD5RwhSxXwviiOAo8ABYRKgmDez06SxwnR9ILQ0clI-FSuMQ60NP-XcgME0CAFZ9Oo2CPCmDyTOQ8zULU6yONskzeKc-jiLEo8ADZPLEmiJJ8yZ4v82TAvk+yMPfULV3CxzCJcmLQO8A1IK83syrUgLmOykKVy-NSIqKgSSt5DYtigeF+TgVkoDoK5CWSzRzlQUI6AhMNoSzAg+2CTtgm7dBYvjRMAR8saJqmjNHlmqAiQRfMUSLSxMkxPEcSrVQgA)